# Install GNU Radio Companion

Tags: gnu, internet-radio

I am trying to install GNU Radio Companion 3.8 in Ubuntu 18.04.
I followed the instructions written in the Wikipedia and watched some YouTube videos, but after writing the commands below, I got some errors as attached in the figure.

Commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases
```

and

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases-3.8
```

I tried to click on these links on the terminal, but all them did not open.
Any idea how to fix these errors?

[image: Errors]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put pictures or screenshots of the terminal. Always copy the text from the terminal and paste it directly in your question. Then format the pasted text as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong repositories in your system, see details below:

1. [Qt4 from *rock-core*](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4/) does not provide packages for 18.04 LTS, so should be removed by

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:rock-core/qt4
   ```
2. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (*bionic*) is actual release, so its packages are located in *archive*, not *old-releases*. You can fix this problem by using command below:

   ```
   sudo sed -i "s/mx.old-releases/archive/g" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
   sudo sed -i "s/old-releases/archive/g" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
   ```
3. For sure re-add correct repositories to the system

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse"
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse"
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse"
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse"
   ```
4. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is supported release, so ESM is not needed for it, remove such repositories by

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/ubuntu-esm-infra
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list
   ```

Then update package lists as usual, install upgrades with new dependencies and install GRC from already correctly chosen [GnuRadio's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnuradio):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnuradio
```

To get 3.8 version you have to purge the [master branch repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnuradio/+archive/ubuntu/gnuradio-master/+packages?field.name_filter=gnuradio&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic) by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-master
```

And also [releases PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnuradio/+archive/ubuntu/gnuradio-releases/+packages?field.name_filter=gnuradio&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic) by

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-releases
```

To stay only with [*gnuradio-releases-3.8*](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnuradio/+archive/ubuntu/gnuradio-releases-3.8/+packages?field.name_filter=gnuradio&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic) PPA.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
The GNU radio has been installed successfully, but the version is 3.9.0.0-git. 
I need 3.8 version since it supports the Radar Toolbox (3.9 is not compatible with this toolbox)
Is there any way to change the version from 3.9 to 3.8 ?

Comment: Great. To get 3.8 version you have to purge the [master branch repository](https://launchpad.net/~gnuradio/+archive/ubuntu/gnuradio-master/+packages?field.name_filter=gnuradio&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic) by
`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge; sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnuradio/gnuradio-master` .

Comment: Thank you so much!
It works perfectly.